# Exhaustive search: minimum number of coins for change. Preserving solution array while using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

The problem consists in minimizing the amount of coins required to give the exact change. There will always be coins of 1 available, therefore the problem will always have a solution.

Some sample coin sets with their solutions for an amount of 40 cents:

coin set  = {1, 5, 10, 20, 25}, solution = {0, 0, 0, 2, 0}

coin set = {1, 5, 10, 20}, solution = {0, 0, 0, 2}

The implementation returns the correct min. number of coins, but I am having trouble preserving the right solution array.

```
int change(int amount, int n, const int* coins, int* solution) {
    if(amount > 0) {
        int numCoinsMin = numeric_limits<int>::max();
        int numCoins;
        int imin;
        for(int i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
            if(amount >= coins[i]) {
                numCoins =  change(amount - coins[i], n, coins, solution) + 1;
                if(numCoins < numCoinsMin) {
                    numCoinsMin = numCoins;
                    imin = i;
                }   
            }   
        }   
        solution[imin] += 1;
        return numCoinsMin;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Sample run:

```
int main() {
    const int n = 4;
    int coins[n] = {1, 5, 10, 20, 25};
    int solution[n] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int amount = 40;

    int min = change(amount, n, coins, solution);
    cout << "Min: " << min << endl;
    print(coins, coins+n); // 1, 5, 10, 20
    print(solution, solution+n); // 231479, 20857, 4296, 199
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you be a little more specific about what you want to have happen?  I'm not sure what you mean by 'preserving the right solution array'

Comment: Updated the question with a sample run. For example, when i run it for 40, the solution array should be 0, 0, 0, 2. Denoting that only 2 coins of 20 cents are needed. But i get those big numbers instead.

Comment: Does this problem require anything besides recursion?  Like do you have to use arrays?  The reason I ask is that I'm not sure I would do it this way unless youre being forced to use arrays for some reason

Comment: No, I am not forced to use arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can still do this using arrays, but I'd alter the structure of the program to make it a little bit cleaner to recurse.

I'm gonna have to pseudocode this for you because I dont use C++ hardly at all but you can probably put it together.  This makes use of modulo division (% in C#, dunno if its the same in C++, you can look it up) which returns ONLY the remainder of a division.  And normal division (/) in most programming languages, will return the whole number answer and ignore any remainders.

```
//declare a function that takes in your change amount and the length of your coins array
int changeCounter(int amount, int coins.length)
      int index = coins.length-1;

      //check to see if we're done... again dunno what 'or' is in C++, I put ||

      if (amount <= 0 || index < 0)
         **return** your results array or whatever you want to do here

      //sees how many of the biggest coin there are and puts that number in the results
      if amount > coins[index]
      {
        result[index]= (amount / coins[index])
        //now recurse with the left over coins and drop to the next biggest coin
        changeCounter((amount % coins[index]), index-1)
      }

      //if the amount isnt greater than the coin size then there obviously arent any of that size, so just drop coin sizes and recurse again
      else
         changeCounter(amount,index-1)
```

This should get you started down the right direction, I tried to comment it for you and I'm sorry I cant put it in perfect C++ syntax for you but it shouldnt be too hard to translate what i did here into what you're trying to do.

If you have any questions let me know

Comment: I just tried to comment this but idk where the heck it went lol.  If you still need to find the minimum number of total coins, just loop through the finished results array and add the values.  Or you can just keep a variable inside the function that adds the result value to it when its doing the math

Comment: I have one question: isn't this a greedy approach? For example, if my coin set  is {1, 5, 10, 20, 25} and the amount is 40. It will pick, 1 of 25, then it will pick 1 of 20 and then 1 of 5. Instead of 2 of 20.

Comment: I didnt realize that you wanted to minimize the overall number of coins you got, I just thought you wanted to efficiently make change.  That makes this more complicated than I can spend time answering it while on my lunch break.  Will look again when I get home if it isnt answered by then.